# RewriteRule - remove params keys and keep values in address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, s3-rewrite-rules

```
RewriteEngine ON    
RewriteRule ^video$ video.php [L]
```

the above line works
`example.com/video` is interpret as `example.com/video.php`

now I need `example.com/video?id=5&s=lorem-ipsum`
to interpret as `example.com/video/5/lorem-ipsum` - and vice versa

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} video?id=([^\s&]+)&s=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ video?id=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ video?/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

doesn't work - in both directions
pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown attempts, please try following .htaccess rules file. These rules are assuming you want to infernally rewrite to index.php you can change php file name in 2nd set of rules as per your requirement.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect Rules from here..
##Redirect 301 to example.com/video/5/lorem-ipsum from example.com/video?id=5&s=lorem-ipsum
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(video)\?id=([^&]*)&s=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite for example.com/video?id=5&s=lorem-ipsum
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?id=$1&s=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244570/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-rewriterule-remove-params-keys-and-kee).